# Possible to customize the remarkGFM MDX generated `id` attribute on footnotes?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, mdxjs

Right now my footnotes citation links as `#user-content-fnref-<name-of-citation>`, so if I do `[^foo]` it will be `#user-content-fnref-foo`. How can I change it so it is a bit cleaner looking in the URL, so maybe it is just `#foo` or `#cite:foo` or something?

I don't see it anywhere in the [docs](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-gfm), but maybe there is another workaround?